# where system() prints output of python in php?

Tags: php, python, exec, system

While running one python script from console,Python prints some lines
for example,..

```
hello,
World.
...
...
```

For displaying on webpage using php, I have tried..

```
exec("sudo -u username python temp.py  >> logdata.log")
```

And print logdata.log. But in that I am getting disordered output on webpage. 
I figured out that It was issue of flushing data.

I have read about **system()** command while googling, that it executes external command and prints output. And also it flushes the output as it happens. So I have tried ..

```
system("sudo -u username Python temp.py")
```

I want to know where it prints output.

Comment: To output statements, like debug statements, from a python code, I strongly suggest to use the `logging` module of python.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use popen .

```
os.popen('sudo -u username Python temp.py').read()
```

or subprocess which is even better:-

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('sudo -u username Python temp.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print "program output:", out
```

Comment: I want to run python script from php. Are you pointing to make another script and then call it from php?

Comment: yes you can do that. you just have to inject this line - exec("python ../xyz/abc.py", $output);